# Bootstrap 3: Is there a way to have a fixed width container for extra small device sizes only?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello there I have been trying to figure out how to set up a fixed width container for the extra small device size in Bootstrap 3.  I know that there is settings out of the box for this size that are auto to be responsive to the smallest devices however, I have been assigned to make a design that has mobile fixed size around 320px wide and centered before it bumps up to the next media query size (@screen-sm-min).

I have tried calling out the container size to change in the media queries but it does not seem to work.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

Should work if you create a media query for max width just below @screen-sm-min

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .container {
    width: 320px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I really appreciate your solution - I spent a while trying to get this dialed in and you fixed it. :)